# Storing many key-values pair correctly?

Tags: mysql

I have some settings files, that will differ in naming of the different settings.

```
setting1 : true
setting2 : false
setting3 : false

settingsss1 : true
settingsss2 : true
settingsss3 : true
```

the naming is user generated so cant really make columns for them.

i though doing something like making a table with

```
Id - Key - Value
```

This would then give 50 entries for a settings file with 50 settings.
Would it be better to just save these as JSON string in a field in the DB as MediumText?

i expect to have around 100 new saves of these every day. giving 100 x 50 x 365 = 1.800.000 entries a year..

The thing is I need to be able to look thru these in a decent way, to compare their settings.

should I go with JSON string or entry pr. parameter. or even a 3rd option?

Comment: MySQL has a [`json` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) which can be indexed and searched efficiently. Which is better, JSON or a key/value table, depends on what you plan to do with it. For a simple flat string key, boolean value I'd start with a table.

Comment: @Schwern My plan is to create some staticstics about the users default values and how many are selecting 'blue' instead of 'red' ect.

the thing is these settings and how many there is, depends on the specific product in the system - but key - value will not be a bad idea even when we talking millions a year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple, flat key/value pairs with simple values, use a normal table. If the values are just true/false use [`boolean`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/) for the value column to save a little space.

If the values can be a mix of types (dates, numbers, strings, lists, nested key/value pairs) use the [`JSON` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html). It can be indexed and searched.

Millions of entries a year is not a lot if they are [properly indexed](https://use-the-index-luke.com/). Handling large amounts of data is what SQL databases are good at.

Comment: They can be a mix, so going with (2 tables just to move them out of the normal product) - havent looked into mysql json so will check that out. thanks

ProductTable
Id

ProductSettingsTable
ProductId - JSONSettings ( JSON )